# Using Knockout to update checked boxes and store selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a checkbox list which I want to be able to select and deselect all of the options, and store the selected values in a knockout array.

Here's my HTML

```
<a><span data-bind="click: selectAllUsers">SELECT ALL</span></a>
<a><span data-bind="click: deselectAllUsers">DESELECT ALL</span></a>
<ul data-bind="foreach: users">
      <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedUsers" />
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the section of my javascript:

```
var userData = //populated earlier
self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectAllUsers = function () {
    self.selectedUsers(userData)
}

self.deselectAllUsers = function () {
    self.selectedUsers([]);
}
```

When the view model is initialized, users and selectedUsers and both initialized to the array of user objects stored in userData. As it stands now, the checkboxes are not automatically checked and when I do check/uncheck one it affects all options in the checkbox. Ideally it would only change the selected checkbox and update selectedUsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have checkboxes with no `value` attribute then you have to assign corresponding value with `checkedValue` binding. In your case:

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedUsers, checkedValue: $data" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xrxskyx8/1/

Comment: @f_martiznez Thanks! The checkedValue: $data was the problem. I do still have one minor issue which is when the SELECT ALL is hit after selecting DESELECT ALL and when some other options are excluded or included, that the SELECT ALL button doesn't actually select all. Sorry if that doesn't really make sense. It seems that the checkboxes aren't updating for all of the users on select all.

Comment: @manufan22122, I've explored your problem. Looks like you tried to initialize multiple observable arrays with *the same array variable*. That's incorrect approach. Use `userData.slice(0)` to create copy of the array (the objects inside will remain original). See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrxskyx8/2/

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm relatively new to Knockout so there's no way I'd have thought of that. Thanks for the help man